# Flex .swc build using org.sonatype.flexmojos is failing

Tags: apache-flex, build, maven, swc

I am trying to create and build a flex library project (.swc) using maven 2 firsttime.
I am able to create directory structure but build is failing.

My maven settings are : 
Maven version : apache-maven-3.0.2

1. mvn  archetype:generate 
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.sonatype.flexmojos
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=flexmojos-archetypes-library
   -DarchetypeVersion=3.8
   -DgroupId=com.test
   -DartifactId=sampleflexproject2 –e

This created the basic project skeleton as per my need.

1. mvn clean install –e –X

I get below exception while executing this command.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-pre-alpha-1:compile-swc (default-compile-swc) on project sampleflexproject2: The parameters 'output' for goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-pre-alpha-1:compile-swc are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-pre-alpha-1:compile-swc (default-compile-swc) on project sampleflexproject2: The parameters 'output' for goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-pre-alpha-1:compile-swc are missing or invalid
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:221)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException:
The parameters 'out put' for goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-pre-alpha-1:compile-swc are missing or invalid
       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.validateParameters(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:688)
       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:580)
       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:525)
       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:98)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

---

Do you foresee any obvious  issue in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please post a simplified version of the POM.

The issue seems to be though that you are missing some configuration for the flexmojos-maven-plugin.  It is complaining that the goal default-compile-swc has no output property defined.

Take a look at your plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-pre-alpha-1</version>
    <configuration>
      <output>${basedir}/target/sampleflexproject2.swf</output>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That though alone will probably not be sufficient for a successful build.

Take a look https://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/maven-sites/flexmojos/4.0-RC1/compile-swc-mojo.html for more information on what should be set in the configuration block.